# Export to *.sif problem

Tags: inkscape

I have asked this question earlier tonight at the Inkscape forum, but the Stack* is more fluent, so here it is:

When I tried to save a very basic drawing as a sif (Synfig Animation) file, the Inkscape have an issue as in image bellow. After that warning, the other window appears with err that the file could not be saved. The OS is very fresh copy of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, and the Inkscape has been recently updated to 0.92.5, I think. Please, any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry, but tech support is generally off-topic on GDSE. 0.92 is an older version now. The most recent version of Inkscape is currently 1.0. I just tried it, no errors were generated when saving as .sif

Comment: This version was shipped with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS from April this year... Thanks for testing on the newest version.

Comment: Aside from switching the version and reporting a bug at https://inkscape.org/report , you could try if the error happens with a file created from the default template, or if it only happens with the specific file you have there. You can copy the contents over to a new document, for example, to test this.